# How to convert rest service response from binary to xml in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

Below is the proxy implemented in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1, this return response in binary format as shown next to the proxy code. Response is expected in the xml response.

Note: This proxy returns xml response in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 as expected.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="postIDMPCall-withheader"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <in>
            <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
               <format>
                  <organizationList xmlns="">
                     <Organization>
                        <sourceRecordId>132</sourceRecordId>
                        <idmpRecordId>0</idmpRecordId>
                        <orgName>depcomp</orgName>
                        <smeNumber/>
                        <psmflCode/>
                        <countryCode>AF</countryCode>
                        <shortName/>
                        <remarks/>
                        <address>addressgger</address>
                        <city>mys</city>
                        <state>kar</state>
                        <postalCode>234</postalCode>
                        <contactPhone/>
                        <phoneExtension/>
                        <faxNumber/>
                        <faxExtension/>
                        <webSite/>
                        <active>YES</active>
                        <organizationId/>
                     </Organization>
                  </organizationList>
               </format>
               <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log>
               <property name="before call" expression="$body"/>
            </log>
            <property name="user" value="system" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="password"
                      value="Password2#"
                      scope="default"
                      type="STRING"/>
            <header name="_user" scope="transport" expression="get-property('user')"/>
            <header name="_password"
                    scope="transport"
                    expression="get-property('password')"/>
            <log>
               <property name="header" expression="get-property('user')"/>
            </log>
            <call blocking="true">
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="http://<ipaddress>:<port>/<rest-Services-path>/UpdateOrganization"
                           format="rest"/>
               </endpoint>
            </call>
            <log>
               <property name="after call" expression="$body"/>
            </log>

 <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>                <header name="To" scope="default" action="remove"/>
                <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
                <send/>
                <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
                <drop/>
             </in>
          </inSequence>
       </target>
    </proxy>
```

**1.Logs:**

```
[ESB] [2016-05-04 15:10:27,222]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/postIDMPCall-withheader.postIDMPCall-withheaderHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:b5814442-977e-43ed-9cc9-f60faa46c5c2, Direction: request, before call = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><organizationList><Organization><sourceRecordId>132</sourceRecordId><idmpRecordId>0</idmpRecordId><orgName>depcomp</orgName><smeNumber></smeNumber><psmflCode></psmflCode><countryCode>AF</countryCode><shortName></shortName><remarks></remarks><address>addressgger</address><city>mys</city><state>kar</state><postalCode>234</postalCode><contactPhone></contactPhone><phoneExtension></phoneExtension><faxNumber></faxNumber><faxExtension></faxExtension><webSite></webSite><active>YES</active><organizationId></organizationId></Organization></organizationList></soapenv:Body> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-05-04 15:10:27,230]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-05-04 15:10:31,066]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:cee9a5c2-1f64-4ff3-a6bd-712785567f8d, Direction: request, after call = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><axis2ns1:binary xmlns:axis2ns1="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/Pgo8b3JnYW5pemF0aW9uUmVzcG9uc2VMaXN0PgogICAgPE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbj4KICAgICAgICA8c291cmNlUmVjb3JkSWQ+MTMyPC9zb3VyY2VSZWNvcmRJZD4KICAgICAgICA8aWRtcFJlY29yZElkPjE3MTY5PC9pZG1wUmVjb3JkSWQ+CiAgICAgICAgPHN1Y2Nlc3M+U1VDQ0VTUzwvc3VjY2Vzcz4KICAgICAgICA8ZXJyb3I+Tm8gRXJyb3JzPC9lcnJvcj4KICAgIDwvT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uPgo8L29yZ2FuaXphdGlvblJlc3BvbnNlTGlzdD4K</axis2ns1:binary></soapenv:Body> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

**2.Response received in binary format:**

```
<axis2ns6:binary xmlns:axis2ns6="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/Pgo8b3JnYW5pemF0aW9uUmVzcG9uc2VMaXN0PgogICAgPE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbj4KICAgICAgICA8c3VjY2Vzcz5GQUlMVVJFPC9zdWNjZXNzPgogICAgICAgIDxlcnJvcj5SZWNvcmQgaXMgbm90IHByb2Nlc3NlZCBzdWNjZXNzZnVsbHkuIFBsZWFzZSBQcm92aWRlIHZhbGlkIFJlcXVlc3QgWE1MPC9lcnJvcj4KICAgIDwvT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uPgo8L29yZ2FuaXphdGlvblJlc3BvbnNlTGlzdD4K</axis2ns6:binary>
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert an XML payload to JSON, set the messageType property to application/json in the axis2 scope before sending message to an endpoint.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Expecting xml response, but returning binary format. I would like to know  why this is returning binary when rest service is invoked? Otherwise can we have any option to convert binary response to xml response. I tried changing the transport to nhttp as well, but this cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you only have inSequence .
And you are logging both before and after call content inside inSequence.

Can you use outSequence and check ? i.e

```
<outSequence>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
    <send/>
</outSequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have enabled the binary message builder/formatter in /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml. If so, disable binary message builder and use default message builders/formatters and try this again.